# Haskell Password Program

Tags: haskell, if-statement, input, passwords, output

I am very new to Haskell and I am attempting to make a simple password program as my first program. I have ran into a problem and I am not very sure on how to fix it. I do not know how to make a second section for the passwords.

```
main = do 
  putStrLn "Hello, Who are you?"
  name <- getLine --User Input
  putStrLn ("Hey " ++ name ++ ", What's the password?")
  pass <- getLine
  if pass == "12345"
      then do 
      putStrLn ("Welcome")
      pw -- Go to password Prompt
      else do
          putStrLn "That is wrong!"
          main --Sent back to beginning
pw = do
putStrLn "What Password do you need?"
```

I do not know how to switch to asking for which password is needed, I am decently sure I know how to list them. The goal is to ask user which password givin a list of websites such as yahoo and then the user pick one and be told the password. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: The stated goal isn't very clear. Do you want an additional prompt to pick a website, and then ask for a password which is validated based on the previously chosen website? If so, you probably want something like a `[(String, String)]` which represents an association of websites to passwords (aside: representing everything as strings isn't good practice). Finally, if you've made attempts which have failed, please include those in the question.

Comment: By prompt I mean that the user is asked to pick from a set list if the user inputs the first password correctly. Not a whole new prompt. Making a somewhat database of passwords for websites. You are probably correct about making to many strings. I am rather new to the programming scene. I apologize. Also with a `[(String , String)]` for example would I use `[(Yahoo, 12345)]` ? If so how would I call upon that?

Comment: I have fixed the problem of pulling up the "What password do you need?" by putting a `do` after `then` , but the problem still lies in bringing up the list of sites and being able to type a site and be told the users password to the site.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to create something that looks like this:

```
What password do you need?
```

*user inputs* `Yahoo`

```
OK, the password for the website "Yahoo" is "asdf"
```

To do this, you will need a collection of websites with their associated passwords. You can represent both websites and passwords as `String`s. The best kind of collection for association lists (which is what you need) is a `Map`. So at the top of your module, import `Data.Map.Strict`:

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
```

Now you have access to all the types and functions documented [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html). Now, you can use `Map.fromList :: [(String,String)] -> Map.Map String String` to turn a `[(String,String)]` (a list of pairs of `String`s) into a `Map.Map String String` (a mapping from `String`s to other `String`s):

```
websites :: Map.Map String String
websites = Map.fromList
  [("Yahoo","asdf")
  ,("Google","meow")
  -- You can add more here if you need to
  ]
```

Now, you can use `Map.lookup :: String -> Map.Map String String -> Maybe String` to lookup a website and get its associated password:

```
Map.lookup "Yahoo" websites ==> Just "asdf"
```

Notice it returned `Just "asdf"` instead of `Nothing` because it was able to find `Yahoo` in `websites`. Now we just need a little bit of IO glue to get the user's input and print out the result, something like:

```
-- Get the website name and put it in websiteName
putStrLn "What password do you need?"
websiteName <- getLine
-- Check our Map for the website name the user gave us
case Map.lookup websiteName websites of
  -- If we found the password, print it out with a nice message
  Just thePassword -> putStrLn $ "OK, your password is: " ++ thePassword
  -- If that website was not in our Map, print an error message
  Nothing -> putStrLn "Website not found :("
```